# passing a variable to map & replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dictionary, replace

I am trying to "clean" a text string that looks something like this:

```
DATABASE:madsat NL:Show all platforms of Salute generated from NAIs with no go mobility.
```

The cleaned string should look like this:

```
Show all platforms of Salute generated from NAIs with no go mobility.
```

I am trying the following code but it doesn't seem to like it when I pass in a variable as the string gets returned unchanged:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('inputQueryExamples.txt',function(data){
        var queryString = data;
        var cleanString = "";
        var db = '';
        $('#database-list').change(function(){
            db = $('#database-list').val();

            // /(^DATABASE:.*\r\n)(^NL.*)/gm
            // http://regex101.com/r/mN4hS2

            regex = new RegExp('(^DATABASE:'+ db +'\r\n)(^NL.*)' ,'gm');

            console.log(db);
            console.log(regex);
            //put code in here to replace un-needed stuff
            $('#what').append(regex + '<br>');

            cleanString = queryString.match(regex);

            var nlString = cleanString.map(function(el) {return el.replace('DATABASE:' + db + ' NL:','');});

            for (i=0; i<nlString.length; i++){
                $('#what').append(nlString[i]+'<br>');
            }
        }); // end change
```

Any insight into what i am doing wrong will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var s = "DATABASE:madsat \r\nNL:Show all platforms of Salute generated from NAIs with no go mobility.";
var db = "madsat";
var r = new RegExp('(^DATABASE:'+ db + '[\\s\\r\\n]*)(^NL:)' ,'gm');
s1.replace(r, "");
//=> "Show all platforms of Salute generated from NAIs with no go mobility."
```

### Update

It took a while for what you're trying to do to sink in (and your sample data was pretty buried in that regex101 link.)

But I think this **[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/lotup/1/edit?js,output)** is something close to what you want to do:  It still does one pass to find the matches, and a second one to remove the unwanted parts of that match.  But the second pass is handled by a single regex `replace` call rather than your double `replaces` above.  (Click the "Run with JS" button and enter "madsat" or "geoquery" in the box.)

This is the relevant code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax('http://jsbin.com/fase/1.js', {dataType:'text'}).done(function(data){
        var $what = $("#what");
        $('#database-list').change(function(){
            var db = $(this).val(),
                base = '(^DATABASE:'+ db + '[\\s\\r\\n]*)(^NL:)';
            var regex1 = new RegExp(base + '(.*)' ,'gm');
            var regex2 = new RegExp(base, 'gm');
            (data.match(regex1) || []).map(function(str) {
                return str.replace(regex2, "");
            }).forEach(function(query) {
                $what.append(query + "<br/>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Note that the two regexes are identical except that the first one matches the remainder of the "NL:"-line, and the second one doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. I went a different way, but I am sure this would also work. Do you know why my solution works, processing array elements twice instead of the way I originally tried?

Answer (score 0):

So this works, but I am not sure why I have to process the string twice. Can anyone explain?

```
var nlString = cleanString.map(function(el) {return el.replace('DATABASE:' + db,'');});
nlString = nlString.map(function(el){return el.replace('NL:',''); });
```

Comment: You're trying to do two different things here.  The regex match to find the parts you want groups together the "DATABASE:" and "NL:" tags you don't want, the newline, and the content you want to keep.  Then your next pass wants to separate the main content from the rest of them.  This will be difficult with a single regex.  See my updated solution for an alternative.